# Proving equality of functions using their restrictions

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I have been going through *Elementary Set Theory* by Enderton and once again I am stuck on an exercise, which goes like this (p.88, exercise 27):

> Assume that $A$ is a set, $G$ is a function, and $f_1$,$f_2$ map $\omega$ into set $A$. Further assume tat for each $n$ in $\omega$ both $f_1|n$ and $f_2|n$ belong to $\DeclareMathOperator{\dom}{dom}\dom G$ and $$f_1(n)=G(f_2|n) \\f_2(n)=G(f_1|n).$$
>
> Prove that $f_1 = f_2$

I have tried applying the induction, both strong and weak, I tried proving that the restrictions are equal,that ranges of restrictions (images) are equal, but so far it gave no results

Any help, as well as hints are more than welcome and appreciated.

Comment: There's a typo, I take it, in that $f_2(n)$ should equal $G(f_2| n)$ not $G(f_1|n)$.

Comment: You are correct,and typo is removed.Thank you for your observation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $n$ be the least place where $f_0$ and $f_1$ differ. Then $f_0|n = f_1|n$. So, $f_0(n) = G(f_1|n) = G(f_0|n) = f_1(n)$, contradicting our assumption.

Comment: How did you conclude that $f_0|n = f_1|n$

Comment: Since $n$ is the least place where they differ, they agree on all values less than $n$. So their restrictions to numbers less than $n$ are equal. Does that help?

Comment: Oh now I see it,it is due to construction of numbers,well that helps.And I will accept your answer as true.Thanks very much